# Why am I getting error Illegal assignment from List<AggregateResult> to List<BOG_Membership__c>

Tags: soql, query, aggregateresult

Why am getting the following error

> Illegal assignment from `List<AggregateResult>` to `List<BOG_Membership__c>`

for this code? And what to do?

```
    List<BOG_Membership__c> aggregates = [
    SELECT Contact__r.AccountId , Contact__r.FirstName , Contact__r.LastName 
        FROM BOG_Membership__c 
        WHERE Contact__r.AccountId = '0012000000fyND0'
        GROUP BY Contact__r.AccountId, Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName    
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate queries always return a:

```
List<AggregateResult>
```

so your code needs to be:

```
List<AggregateResult> aggregates = [...];
```

(Adding the `GROUP BY` turns the query into an aggregate query.)

See e.g. [Working with SOQL Aggregate Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) for examples of how to `get` the result values from the `AggregateResult` object.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a `GROUP BY` clause in your query, salesforce is returning a list type of `AggregateResult`. So you have to have something like

```
List<AggregateResult> aggregates = [
    SELECT Contact__r.AccountId , Contact__r.FirstName , Contact__r.LastName 
        FROM BOG_Membership__c 
        WHERE Contact__r.AccountId = '0012000000fyND0'
        GROUP BY Contact__r.AccountId, Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName    
];
```

I'd suggest few more things here when it comes to iterating over a list of `AggregateResult`. You have to use [aliases](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_alias.htm) for your fields which gives you the ease of access them inside the loop. If you don't and if you have more than one same fields (Id, Name, etc. in different lookup objects) then you will be in trouble.

```
List<AggregateResult> aggregates = [
        SELECT Contact__r.AccountId aid , Contact__r.FirstName cfName, Contact__r.LastName clName
            FROM BOG_Membership__c 
            WHERE Contact__r.AccountId = '0012000000fyND0'
            GROUP BY Contact__r.AccountId, Contact__r.FirstName, Contact__r.LastName    
    ];
for(AggregateResult ar : aggregates){
    System.debug(ar.get('aid'));
    System.debug(ar.get('cfName'));
    System.debug(ar.get('clName'));
}
```